# How do I get MySQL's "load data" to properly import very large integers into a binary(16) field?

Tags: mysql, mysql-loadfile

I have a file containing ipv6 addresses represented as very large integers.  When I import it into mysql the data is wrong.  What do I need to do in order to get the load data to properly import the data into a binary(16) column?

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `ipv6_test` (
  `ip` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

CSV file to import, ipv6_test.csv:

```
"58569107296622255421594597096899477505","test"
```

MySQL import command:

```
mysql> load data local infile 'ipv6_test.csv' into table ipv6_test fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Query:

```
select ip, INET6_NTOA(ip), name from ipv6_test;
```

Incorrect Results:

```
+------------------+-----------------------------------------+------+
| ip               | INET6_NTOA(ip)                          | name |
+------------------+-----------------------------------------+------+
| 5856910729662225 | 3538:3536:3931:3037:3239:3636:3232:3235 | test |
+------------------+-----------------------------------------+------+
```

Expected Results:

```
+------------------+-----------------------------------------+------+
| ip               | INET6_NTOA(ip)                          | name |
+------------------+-----------------------------------------+------+
| ? binary data ?  | 2C0F:FFF0:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 | test |
+------------------+-----------------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: Why not just the textual representation? This is far easier to read, query, and work with. If you're doing a lot of IP work, it's worth noting Postgres has a native IP address column type.

Comment: The file to import comes from a third party.  We already have a process that imports ipv4 addresses which works.  I'd rather just change the load data command to handle the larger ipv6 addresses than write a program or script to convert these decimal representation of ipv6 addresses to a more typical format.

Comment: Your third party is doing it completely wrong. This is one of the worst ways to represent IP addresses. They're making your life miserable to shave a few bytes off their file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INET6_NTOA()` takes a raw binary address and converts it to a hex version. You're passing in an integer, which is invalid.

`"58569107296622255421594597096899477505"` becomes `0x353835363931303732393636...` as raw hex, which is where that weird value comes from.

I'm not sure that MySQL can manipulate 128-bit numbers *and* account for the endian-issues that crop up as well. Apart from `NUMERIC` types, the largest value it can handle internally appears to be 64-bit. You'll need to convert your data before writing the CSV.

For example, if you can convert it to look like this in the file:

```
0x2c0ffff0000000000000000000000001,test
```

Then you can import that as as a raw binary value.